# can we pass multiple args in Get Json Value key?

Tags: python-2.7, http, robotframework

I'm for now fetching one arg value through **Get Json Value** key

```
Create Session  Get_Inventory_Details   ${Base_URL}                 
${Headers}= Create Dictionary   Content-Type=application/json   Authorization=bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6InByaXRpc3dhaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1Njc1MTQ2NDd9.o3qTPbj2KH6AgHpIf1BLV5nOlGL-fR83wSGAYyuWsBQ              
${Response}=    Get Request Get_Inventory_Details   inventorybyOutlet/7 headers=${Headers}          
Log To Console  ${Response.status_code}                     
Log Many    ${Response.content}                     
${actual_response}= Convert To String   ${Response.status_code}                 
Should Be Equal ${actual_response}  200 
${quantity}=    Get Json Value  ${Response.content} /0/currentInventory             
Run Keyword If  ${quantity}>10  Log Threshold Condition Pass    ELSE    Log Threshold Condition Fail
```

What can be the possible way out if I want to pass more than one arg in **Get Json Value**

I have tried

```
${quantity}=    Get Json Value  ${Response.content} /0/currentInventory/0/itemid
```

[Reference to Json Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVQpe.png)

```
[ 
   { 
      "isInventoryOperationEnable":1,
      "itemId":1,
      "name":"Afghani Chicken Tikka Biryani (Heavy Eater)",
      "posName":"Afghani Chicken Tikka Biryani (Heavy Eater)",
      "image":"https://d30mle0t4iy75h.cloudfront.net/websiteV2/images/menuItems/AfghaniTikkaBiryani.jpg",
      "typeid":2,
      "isCombo":0,
      "currentInventory":100,
      "categoryId":1,
      "categoryname":"Biryani",
      "subCategoryId":1,
      "sequenceInCategory":1
   },
   { 
      "isInventoryOperationEnable":1,
      "itemId":3,
      "name":"Chicken Tikka Biryani (Heavy Eater)",
      "posName":"Chicken Tikka Biryani (Heavy Eater)",
      "image":"https://d30mle0t4iy75h.cloudfront.net/websiteV2/images/menuItems/ChickenTikkaBiryani.jpg",
      "typeid":2,
      "isCombo":0,
      "currentInventory":100,
      "categoryId":1,
      "categoryname":"Biryani",
      "subCategoryId":1,
      "sequenceInCategory":14
   }
      ]
```

But RobotFramework throws error as :- 
**JsonPointerException: Document '' does not support indexing, must be mapping/sequence or support __getitem__**

[Error Message on RobotFramework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBFmI.png)

Please can anyone help in finding out a way how to pass more than 1 arg in this case

Thank You

Comment: Would be nice to have that JSON data so that it could be copy-pasted (i.e., not in an image format).

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that has a small block of hard-coded json data that mimics the real data but is as small as possible to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added a small block of Json data for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create Session  Get_Inventory_Details   ${Base_URL}                 
${Headers}= Create Dictionary   Content-Type=application/json   Authorization=bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6InByaXRpc3dhaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1Njc1MTQ2NDd9.o3qTPbj2KH6AgHpIf1BLV5nOlGL-fR83wSGAYyuWsBQ              
${Response}=    Get Request Get_Inventory_Details   inventorybyOutlet/7 headers=${Headers}          
Log To Console  ${Response.status_code}                     
Log Many    ${Response.content}                     
${actual_response}= Convert To String   ${Response.status_code}                 
Should Be Equal ${actual_response}  200 
${response_content_json}=   To Json    ${Response.content}    #To Json is from RequestsLibrary
${quantity}=    Set Variable    ${response_content_json}[0][currentInventory]
Run Keyword If  ${quantity}>10  Log Threshold Condition Pass    ELSE    Log Threshold Condition Fail
```

In this case, `${quantity}` was `100`.

Note two things:

- after converting to JSON, variable values can be accessed alike `dictionary` type variables
- `To JSON` keyword is from [RequestsLibrary](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html)